# Left Join - Unknown Column Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been recently going through my database code trying to improve on my old code with new techniques to make it more efficient. Recently I have been looking to JOINs and I spotted what I thought was a perfect opportunity to test it out.

I am currently using the following two queries to form a list of groups for a user:

```
SELECT g.group_id, g. name 
FROM assigned_groups ag, user_groups g 
WHERE ag.user_id=:user_id AND ag.group_id=g.group_id

SELECT g.group_id, g. name 
FROM users u, user_groups g 
WHERE u.user_id=:user_id AND u.base_group=g.group_id
```

Those two select statements give me the list but I would like to join them into one. The only catch is a user may or may not have any groups listed in "assigned_groups". Ie thats optional.

From what I understand that means I need a LEFT or RIGHT join. I have currently the following syntax:

```
SELECT g.group_id, g. name 
FROM 
  user_groups g, users u 
  LEFT JOIN assigned_groups ag ON ag.user_id=:user_id AND ag.group_id=g.group_id 
WHERE 
 u.base_group=g.group_id AND u.user_id=:user_id
```

**However this is giving me the following error:**
*Unknown column 'g.group_id' in 'on clause'*

Here is an image of my table structure:
[image]

Comment: Look into UNION instead of joins for this problem. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Inner and outer not left and right, but this looks like a union anyway.

Comment: I have updated my post with an image of my table structure.

Comment: have you tried [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8961196/1158170) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from implicit to explicit JOIN.

This makes the g alias available later on in the FROM clause.

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.name, 
    ag.name -- guessing here
FROM 
  users u
  JOIN
  user_groups g ON u.base_group = g.group_id 
  LEFT JOIN 
  assigned_groups ag ON ag.user_id = :user_id AND ag.group_id = g.group_id 
WHERE 
  u.user_id = :user_id
```

Note: this also removes ambiguity in "which join to do first"

However, I think you really want this. It depends on the relationship between `u` and `ag`

Edit 2, after more comments

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.name , 1 as IsBaseGroup
FROM 
  users u
  JOIN
  user_groups g ON u.base_group = g.group_id 
WHERE 
  u.user_id = :user_id
UNION
SELECT ag.group_id, ag.name, 0 as IsBaseGroup
FROM 
  users u
  JOIN 
  assigned_groups ag ON u.user_id = ag.user_id
  JOIN
  user_groups g ON ag.group_id  = g.group_id 
WHERE 
  u.user_id = :user_id;
```

Edit, after comment.

```
SELECT 
   g.group_id, g.name, 
   CASE WHEN u.base_group = g.group_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsBaseGroup
FROM 
  users u
  JOIN 
  assigned_groups ag ON u.user_id = ag.user_id
  JOIN
  user_groups g ON ag.group_id  = g.group_id 
WHERE 
  u.user_id = :user_id
```

Comment: Assigned groups is just a join table. It only has "group_id" and "user_id" as fields in it. When I tried your second example after removing the non existent ag.name field it gave me an error about cardinality in select statements.

Comment: @Petty_Crim: it's quite unclear what you want to do now. I've added another example... if this is wrong then please update your question to help us to help you...

Comment: I have updated my post with an image for clarification. Basically the base_group field contains a group_id number. Every user has a set base_group but may also have an "assigned group" as well.

Comment: @Petty_Crim: updated 3rd example with extra flag. This achieves the same as what you want in one query and differentiates the "main" group

Comment: Nope I tried your latest one its still only giving me the row in base_group but not also the one in assigned groups

Comment: Actually scrap its doing the opposite now. It finds the assigned groups but doesn't give me the base_group.

Comment: @Petty_Crim: Is base_group included in assigned_groups? Or does it bypass this?

Comment: No base_group is not included in assigned_groups its in the users table. If you mean could a "base_group" also be in the assigned_groups tables thats a NO but the id's in base_group do exist in the groups_table.

Comment: Ok I solved by using your second query by swapping ag.name with g.name. I also removed those "0 as IsBaseGroup" field things as I don't see what they do. Seems to work without them.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you're applying `LEFT JOIN` to `users u` on the left and `assigned_group ag` on the right. **`user_groups g` is not part of the outer join and cannot be referenced in the `ON` clause.**

Did you mean something like:

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.name
FROM users u,
     user_groups g LEFT JOIN assigned_groups ag
         ON ag.user_id=:user_id AND ag.group_id=g.group_id
WHERE u.base_group=g.group_id AND u.user_id=:user_id
```

Comment: I tried your technique but its only getting me results for "base_group" but ignores anything in assigned groups.

Answer (score 1):

Try with parentesis on every pair of tables.

Example on your query:

```
SELECT g.group_id, g. name 
FROM 
  (user_groups g, users u )
  LEFT JOIN assigned_groups ag ON ag.user_id=:user_id AND ag.group_id=g.group_id 
WHERE 
 u.base_group=g.group_id AND u.user_id=:user_id
```

More general example:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*
FROM 
  (
     (
       (table1 a, table2 b)
       , table3 c
     )
     LEFT JOIN table4 d ON a.id=d.id and b.idx = d.idx
  )
WHERE 
 u.base_group=g.group_id AND u.user_id=:user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this one will help you. The ag.name may have NULL when it returns rows as you have probably understood that. If you need that then exclude g.name field from the select.

```
SELECT u.name,ug.name
FROM  users u 
INNER JOIN assigned_groups ag 
ON u.user_id=ag.user_id
INNER JOIN user_groups ug
ON ag.group_id=ug.group_id    
WHERE u.user_id=:user_id
```

Cheers

Comment: i've updated the query according to the ER. hope it will help

Answer (score -1):

Have fun with it

```
SELECT g.group_id, g.name
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN assigned_groups ag 
      ON  ag.group_id=g.group_id
LEFT JOIN users u
      ON  u.base_group=g.group_id
WHERE u.user_id=:user_id OR ag.user_id=:user_id
```